# Get back my Stack Overflow account

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, post-ban

Now I understood that my questions must have a value for future users, it was my fault.

I didn't know that deleting questions indicates that the material posted isn't right for Stack Overflow.

Now I want to undelete my question and edit it in a manner that help future users, but I don't know how to undelete it.

Also I want to get my account back.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to do it is to flag one of your existing questions for moderator attention:

[image: Flag example]

Then click "other" and in the description, explain the situation:

[image: Selecting other]

Obviously if you know the specific questions you want to undelete, you can tell the moderator which ones to undelete, rather than undelete all of the questions. But I would focus on the ones you self deleted, as opposed to than anything that was deleted by a moderator or the community (if you have any), since you'll have an easier time fixing those questions (and, in general, mods are less willing to undelete community-deleted questions).

Once undeleted, then it is just a matter of fixing them. Sometimes, it might be helpful to go to chat (if you have enough reputation points) or post a Meta Stack Overflow question linking to the fixed questions if you need help getting attention to the question, and/or getting help improving the question.  however, depending on how poor the question is, you may need to act very quickly to fix your question as it may attract more downvotes once it is undeleted.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you,  I am working on it now =)

Comment: +1 for freehand red circles

Answer (score 5):

<s>You find the questions which you think that can be improved (As in, improved enough to gain upvotes and be reopened), those questions should be flagged for moderator attention stating you want to "undelete this question for improvement".</s>

As @Bo correctly noted, it's impossible to find your deleted questions. In this case, flag one undeleted question, and state you want to undelete all of your deleted questions.

Once the mod will undelete your question (which he will, there's no reason why he wouldn't), you edit your question extensively, to improve it (Be it formatting, generalization, adding code snippets, clarifying). Then, you can do one of two things:

- Flag it for moderator attention **again**, stating you want to reopen it to give it a second chance after editing it.
- Bring it to the community's awareness by going to chat or posting it here on meta under the [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag.

When enough of your posts are improved, the post ban would be lifted **automatically**.

Good luck, it's rare to see a "bad" community member go "good", hope you do well!!

Comment: A problem is that you cannot see the deleted questions...

Comment: Just sent asking the admins to undelete my only self deleted question to edit it and improve it.
I think I will join the good side =)

Comment: @AhmedKato: Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I've undeleted your two recent self-deleted questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800498/comparison-between-threading-aspects
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627283/qt-export-dll-in-visual-studio-2010

The other deleted question you had was closed and deleted by members of the community, so I won't reverse that.

These questions still need some work to get them into better shape, because one was closed and the other was accumulating close votes. A little more detail in the question and a specific focus on a technical issue might be needed here.

Comment: Thank you, I will start working on them now =)

Comment: Do I have a deadline to edit ?? also I know the answer of the second question do I write the question and answer it?

Comment: @AhmedKato the 2 questions Brad undeleted are 2 you deleted the questions yourself, not the community, so I would guess the there isn't an official deadline, but you would be best served to get them fixed sooner rather than later as they might attract close or delete votes in the future if you leave them as-is.